# How to loop through a hash in ruby and determine a final value

Tags: ruby

I have a variable that prints like this:

```
{:type1=>:poor, :type2=>:avg, :type3=>:best}
```

I want to iterate through this hash and print out a final value based on following rules

- if value for any of the types is `:best` then final value is `best`
- if value for any of the types is `:avg` and there are no `best` then final value is `avg`
- otherwise final value is `poor`

basically the strongest ones wins.

I've tries the following

```
def final_value(values)
  val = "poor"
  values.each do |key, val|

  end
  val
end
```

Comment: You also have symbols `:poor` etc, but you wrote as if there are variable/methods `poor` etc. Then, you are even mentioning strings `"poor"` etc.

Comment: I'm simply treating them as strings in my loop even though they are symbols

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Hash's has_value? method.

```
val = :poor;
val = :avg  if values.has_value?(:avg);
val = :best if values.has_value?(:best);
val
```

Comment: +1 good answer - indeed, iteration is unnecessary! you can slightly improve it by looking for `best` first, cause then you might not need to look for `avg`

Comment: @alfasin The implementation of the `has_value?` method does iteration.  Iteration is necessary, it's just a matter of explicit or implicit iteration.

Comment: @AlexWayne I think that you understood what I meant didn't you ? :) In case not: I was comparing it to cainy393's answer - I meant that it is unnecessary to **implement** iteration since Ruby does it for you using `has_value?`. The "implicit" way is more elegant - that's what I meant.

Comment: BTW, on a second thought, iteration is actually NOT needed, if the implementation would change to hold an "opposite" Hash (one in which values point to the boolean "true") -it's could be done in O(1). I think that the reason it's not implemented is in order to not waste memory-space, which is a good reason. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this?

```
final_val = :poor
values.each() do |val|
    if val = :avg && final_val = :poor
        final_val = :avg
    end
    if val = :best && final_val = :avg
        final_val = :best
    end
end
return final_val
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you need as follows:

```
def final_value(values)
    val = :poor;
    values.each do|k, v|
        if(v==:best)
            val=:best;
            break;
        elsif(val==:poor && v==:avg)
            val=:avg;
        end
    end
    puts "Final value is: "+val.to_s;
end

values = {:type1=>:poor, :type2=>:avg, :type3=>:best};
final_value(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def compare(h,val)
 m = ((h.has_value?(val) and val != :poor) ? ((val == :best or h.has_value?(:best))? :best : :avg ) : :poor)
end
h = {:type1=>:poor, :type2=>:avg, :type3=>:best}

p compare(h,:avg) #:best
p compare(h,:trr) #:poor
p compare(h,:best) #:best
```